# SQL Server Agent (2012) Inserting Quotes Into SSIS Parameters

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, parameter-passing, sql-server-agent

I have a SQL Server Agent Job that is running an SSIS package and passing in a project-level parameter. The parameter value I typed in is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe
```

The package was giving me an "invalid characters" error so I added a step in the package to write the parameter value to a table. It came out like this:

```
C:\Program "Files" (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe
```

For further info, when I look up the job's command in msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps, it contains this:

```
/Par "\"$Project::exe_7zip\"";"\"C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe\""
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: you should pass param like "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe"

Comment: This seems to create the value "C:\Program "Files" (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" as opposed to just C:\Program "Files" (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe.